# Is there any way to get data between specific time intervals?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

For example, I want to query data for events in the last two days from a table. Currently, using `between date_sub(CURRENT_DATE,2) and date_sub(CUREENT_DATE,1)`. What I want to do actually is get data from 7 AM two days before to 7 AM today. How can I do that in hive?

Answer (score 0):

The function that you use has only date. If you can concatenate time in hh:mm:ss format. You will be able to achieve what you are looking for. If it doesn't work you can try converting to datetime.

```
between concat( date_sub(CURRENT_DATE,2),' 07:00:000') and concat( date_sub(CURRENT_DATE,2),' 07:00:000')
```